# Why is my UITextView not showing in my Swift/iOS app's custom table cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My custom tableview cell has a label and textview. When I run the app I only see the label and not the textview.

Here is my View

[image]

Here is my ViewController:

```
class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var authorAndTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textTextView: UITextView!
}

class WallViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var postTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.authorAndTimeLabel?.text = "foo"
        cell.textTextView?.text = "bar"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is what I see when I run the app:

[image]

I have the classes set correctly in the interface builder and all the outlets are correct.

Here are the textViews constraints

[image]

It's showing position, size, and scrollable content size are ambiguous for the textview and position is ambiguous for the label, but I don't understand why since I set constraints for all four sides of the textview and constraints for the top left corner of the label. Shouldn't that be enough?

[image]

Why is the TextView not showing?

How do I get it to show with a paragraph of text?

Comment: Have you added constraints? ,&Use `hightForRowForIndexpath` with some value.

Comment: Did you tried to use `Debug View Hierarchy`?

Comment: @ovov the textview doesn't seem to be there when I Debug View Hierarchy.

Comment: @matt it's hooked up to the textTextView and the constraints are fine. I posted a picture of them. I don't know what else to debug. I've checked everything I can think of.

Comment: @Jack I've posted the constraints. Why do I need to use hightForRowForIndexpath? The tableView seems to be displaying fine.

Comment: add your label height 30 and then add texttextview top constraint 2 and leading, trailing, and bottom constraints 0. then run your app

Comment: @Tan, I changed the labels height to 30 and made textview's constraints be 2 from the top, and 0 from the left, right, and bottom (I deleted the already existing constraints for left, right, and bottom from the textview). I still get the same problem.

Comment: @MatthewDrill don't put your textview in the cell container view. first add a uiview to container then add your textview to that view. The i hope your will find your answere.

Comment: @Tan That doesn't seem to work. Is there some sort of process for debugging these kinds of things?

Comment: after doing above process (add view to container). uncheck your textview's scroll enable property from storyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147124/discussion-between-matthew-drill-and-tan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set your textView width fixed (i.e 100 or 150)

add protocol :

```
 UITextViewDelegate
```

at cellForRow at IndexPath mehod add

```
  cell.textviewDemo.delegate = self
```

add the delegate method to end editing when press return

```
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if (text == "\n")
    {

        self.view.endEditing(true);
        return false;
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: How do I set the textView width to fixed? I can't find that setting.